# Area between parabolas

Tags: calculus, integration, area

I would like to calculate the area between these 2 curves. As you can see the first one is

$x^2 = αy$ and the second one is $y^2 = 2αx$

What I tried is to solve the equation when the two curves are equal $x^2/α = \sqrt{2αx}$. After, that I would calculate the integral of the two functions in all the solutions I found from the above equation.

Do you think this is a correct approach or I need to see it differently. My question is mostly asked because it has the parameter $α$ and I am not quite sure how that changes the things.

Comment: It's two parabolas here, not "a parabola and a hyperbola". Other than that, your approach is perfectly fine.

Comment: Maybe, psychologically, it will help to replace $\alpha$ with $\pi$.  Work the problem through, then replace all the $\pi$ with $\alpha$ again.  I know, it sounds silly, but it can help.

Answer (score 1):

We will first rewrite the equations as functions of $x$:

$$f(x) = \frac{x^{2}}{a}$$

$$g(x)=\sqrt{2ax}$$

We may take the square root for the second because we only care about the positive branch. Setting $f(x) = g(x)$:

$$\frac{x^{2}}{\alpha} = \sqrt{2\alpha x}$$

$$x^{4} = \alpha^{2}\cdot 2\alpha x$$

$$x^{4} - 2\alpha^{3}x = 0$$

$$x(x^{3} - 2\alpha^{3}) = 0$$

$$x = 0, \sqrt[3]{2}\alpha$$

Note that $g(x) > f(x)$ for $0 < x < \sqrt[3]{2}\alpha$. Then, we find the area between the curves:

$$A = \int_{0}^{\sqrt[3]{2}\alpha}g(x) - f(x)\ dx = \int_{0}^{\sqrt[3]{2}\alpha}\sqrt{2\alpha x} - \frac{x^{2}}{\alpha}\ dx = \bigg(\frac{2\sqrt{2\alpha}x^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3} - \frac{x^{3}}{3\alpha}\bigg)\bigg\vert_{0}^{\sqrt[3]{2}\alpha}$$

$$=\frac{2\sqrt{2\alpha}}{3}(\sqrt[3]{2}\alpha)^{\frac{3}{2}} - \frac{1}{3\alpha}(\sqrt[3]{2}\alpha)^{3} = \frac{4\alpha^{2}}{3} - \frac{2\alpha^{2}}{3} = \boxed{\frac{2\alpha^{2}}{3}}$$

When you think about it, it makes sense that the area scales with $\alpha^{2}$ because one of the curves scales linearly with $\alpha$ in the $x$-direction, and the other scales in the $y$-direction.

Comment: Thanks Joshua. This is what I found too.